# How to show GridView's header and footer if all rows are deleted

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have GridView with CRUD operations, on load I'm adding one empty row with no data just to show the grid, after that I can add new rows, update, delete, but when I delete **all rows** my grid disappears and I lose Grid's header and footer.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = new object[] { null };
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Is there any solution to set this row fixed?

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.DataItem == null)
        {
            e.Row.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see, you want your `GridView` to have headers and footers when there is no data inside of it. In ASP.NET 4.0+, they had introduced a attribute `ShowHeaderWhenEmpty`, You should set it to `true` if you want to display the header even of the `GridView`.

Comment: And ShowFooterWhenEmpty !?